# WPF: How to display combination of textblocks and textboxes inflow?

Tags: wpf

I want to display combination of textblocks and textboxes inflow with fixed width. Remember it's multi-line text. Which container control I should use to achieve this. I tried using StackPanel with fixed width but it doesn't work.

Ex:

Some text bla bla #Text box# again Some text bla 
bla #txtbx# again some text #Textbox# text some 
text bla again some text #textbox# text some text bla

Comment: See if this post helps - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6696624/442444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TextElement` to do this like

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Run Text="I comma " />
    <TextBox Width="100" Text="recruit's name" />            
    <Run Text="comma  do solemnly swear by " />
    <TextBox Width="150" Text="recruit's deity of choice"/>            
    <Run Text=" to uphold the Laws and Ordinances of the City of Ankh-Morpork" />
</TextBlock>
```

You might need to adjust the TextBoxes margins to move them in line with the other text.

Comment: To the OP: Remember that `TextBlock` content is mixed xml. In this example, newlines become spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FlowDocument, ie:

```
<FlowDocumentReader xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Bold>Some bold text in the paragraph.</Bold>

                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu ipsum vitae sem elementum mollis tempor et neque. 
            </Paragraph>


            <Paragraph>
                <TextBox Text="I'm a textbox"></TextBox>
                <Button Content="Click Me"></Button>
            </Paragraph>
                    <List>
                <ListItem>
                    <Paragraph>ListItem 1</Paragraph>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                    <Paragraph>ListItem 2</Paragraph>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                    <Paragraph>ListItem 3</Paragraph>
                </ListItem>
            </List>

        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentReader>
```

to obtain this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the `WrapPanel` ? I think this is the best container to do what you want. You can use it like a `StackPanel` and depending on its size and items size, the `WrapPanel` organizes items to feel the space horizontaly and verticaly.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a ItemsControls with ItemsContainer as WrapPanel

Bind the ItemsControl with a Collection in ViewModel and then Design your DataTemplate in View

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"/>
     <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"/>
     <TextBox Grid.Column="3"/>
<Grid/>
```

Or

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition/>
     <RowDefinition/>
     <RowDefinition/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"/>
 <TextBox Grid.Row="1"/>
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"/>
 <TextBox Grid.Row="3"/>
 <Grid/>
```

Or any Combination You need

If you need any special with of TextBlocks of TextBoxes you may set width like this

```
      <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
```